# GPG sign not using keys from gpg-connect-agent

Tags: gnupg, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2, openpgp

I'm trying to make PGP keys sharing from Windows 10 to WSL 2 with Ubuntu 20.04.

I'm using this tool: https://github.com/BlackReloaded/wsl2-ssh-pageant

My current situation is that with `gpg-connect-agent 'keyinfo --list' /bye` all my Windows GPG keys are listed, but with `gpg --list-keys` an empty list is returned.

```
$ gpg-connect-agent 'keyinfo --list' /bye
S KEYINFO 9BD09C... D - - - P - - -
S KEYINFO BBF58D... D - - - P - - -
S KEYINFO D62ED0... D - - - P - - -
OK
```

Signing attemps fails with 'No secret key', but I think this is spected, as gpg --list-keys are empty: `echo "test" | gpg --sign -u mail@none.com`

Any clues why is this happenning?

What is the relation with gpg and gpg-connect-agent?

**Setup:**

1. Start a fresh WSL 2 session with `wsl --shutdown'
2. Remove 'S.gpg-agent' file
3. Create pipe with `setsid socat UNIX-LISTEN:$GPG_AGENT_SOCK,fork EXEC:"${WSL_TOOLS}/wsl2-ssh-pageant.exe --gpg S.gpg-agent",nofork &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your public key to WSL.

As stated here https://wiki.gnupg.org/AgentForwarding:

> It is important to note that to work properly GnuPG on the remote system still needs your public keys.

**Steps:**

1. On Windows, export your public key with `gpg --export -a 'mail@none.com' > public.key`;
2. On WSL, import your public key with `gpg --import public.key`.

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if it described how to do so, to still be useful in the future even if the wiki link breaks.